# Is there a more efficient way to write max(A*x,min(y,B*x))?

Tags: logic, algorithms, computational-complexity

Suppose we know that $B > A$.  Right now,

$$\max\{A \cdot x,\min(y,B\cdot x)\}$$

requires two multiplication operations to evaluate.

Is there a way to rewrite this using max/min notation such that I only need one multiplication operation (and no other floating point operations such as division) to evaluate?

EDIT: Updated this to place an additional constraint.

Comment: For the  coding part of your question, this may not be the best site ...

Comment: Yes, I was debating whether to put this on a coding-based stackexchange/overflow site or to put this here... I was hoping the mathematicians here could work some magic with the max/min logic.

Comment: Ah!  So maybe ask that: is there some different way to mathematically define this function exploiting the min/max interplay?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

$$x \cdot max(A,min(y/x,B))$$

but now of course you have a division operation. It *is* only 1 multiplication operator though :)

Comment: That's a good point haha.  I should define my question a bit better...

Comment: With this formulation you need to check whether $x = 0$ to avoid trying to divide by $0$.